# Python game on the HTML page

Tags: python, html, pygame

I'm new to python, and my friend asked me to make a python snake game for our website. I made it, but there is only python code shows on our website. But we need that there is our game shows, so people can play this game. I've tried this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
 <iframe src="main.py"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

also, here is python code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
import pygame_menu

pygame.init()

bgImg = pygame.image.load("just_white_background.jpg")

# colors
FRAME_COLOR = (216, 191, 222)  # pale purple
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
HEADER_COLOR = (195, 155, 204)
PURPLE = (205, 147, 219)  # 205, 147, 219
SNAKE_COLOR = (139, 59, 155)
FOOD_COLOR = (139, 59, 155)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

# blocks
BLOCK_COUNT = 20
BLOCK_SIZE = 20

# margins
BLOCK_MARGIN = 2
HEADER_MARGIN = 70

size = [BLOCK_SIZE * BLOCK_COUNT + 2 * BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_MARGIN * BLOCK_COUNT,
        BLOCK_SIZE * BLOCK_COUNT + 2 * BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_MARGIN * BLOCK_SIZE + HEADER_MARGIN]

print(size)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake Game")
timer = pygame.time.Clock()
textFont = pygame.font.SysFont('courier', 24)

class SnakeBlock:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def is_inside(self):
        return 0 <= self.x < BLOCK_SIZE and 0 <= self.y < BLOCK_SIZE

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, SnakeBlock) and self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y

def get_random_empty_block():
    x = random.randint(0, BLOCK_COUNT - 1)
    y = random.randint(0, BLOCK_COUNT - 1)
    empty_block = SnakeBlock(x, y)
    while empty_block in snake_blocks:
        empty_block.x = random.randint(0, BLOCK_COUNT - 1)
        empty_block.y = random.randint(0, BLOCK_COUNT - 1)
    return empty_block

def draw_block(color, row, column):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, [BLOCK_SIZE + column * BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_MARGIN * (column + 1),
                                     HEADER_MARGIN + BLOCK_SIZE + row * BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_MARGIN * (row + 1),
                                     BLOCK_SIZE,
                                     BLOCK_SIZE])

def start_the_game():

    def get_random_empty_block():
        x = random.randint(0, BLOCK_COUNT - 1)
        y = random.randint(0, BLOCK_COUNT - 1)
        empty_block = SnakeBlock(x, y)
        while empty_block in snake_blocks:
            empty_block.x = random.randint(0, BLOCK_COUNT - 1)
            empty_block.y = random.randint(0, BLOCK_COUNT - 1)
        return empty_block

    snake_blocks = [SnakeBlock(9, 3), SnakeBlock(9, 4), SnakeBlock(9, 5)]
    food = get_random_empty_block()
    d_row = buf_row = 0
    d_column = buf_column = 1
    score = 0
    speed = 1

    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                print("exit")
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP and d_column != 0:
                    buf_row = -1
                    buf_column = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and d_column != 0:
                    buf_row = 1
                    buf_column = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and d_row != 0:
                    buf_row = 0
                    buf_column = -1
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and d_row != 0:
                    buf_row = 0
                    buf_column = 1

        screen.fill(FRAME_COLOR)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, HEADER_COLOR, [0, 0, size[0], HEADER_MARGIN])

        score_total = textFont.render(f"Score: {score}", 0, BLACK)
        speed_label = textFont.render(f"Speed: {speed}", 0, BLACK)
        screen.blit(speed_label, (250, 20))
        screen.blit(score_total, (20, 20))

        for row in range(BLOCK_COUNT):
            for column in range(BLOCK_COUNT):
                if (row + column) % 2 == 0:
                    color = PURPLE
                else:
                    color = WHITE

                    draw_block(color, row, column)

        head = snake_blocks[-1]
        if not head.is_inside():
            print("Game Over")
            break
            # pygame.quit()
            # sys.exit()

        draw_block(FOOD_COLOR, food.x, food.y)
        for block in snake_blocks:
            draw_block(SNAKE_COLOR, block.x, block.y)


        pygame.display.flip()

        if food == head:
            score += 1
            speed = score // 5 + 1
            snake_blocks.append(food)
            food = get_random_empty_block()

        d_row = buf_row
        d_column = buf_column
        new_head = SnakeBlock(head.x + d_row, head.y + d_column)

        if new_head in snake_blocks:
            print('crashed yourself')
            break
            # pygame.quit()
            # sys.exit()

        snake_blocks.append(new_head)
        snake_blocks.pop(0)

        timer.tick(3 + speed)

# game menu


menu = pygame_menu.Menu(220, 300, 'Snake Game',
                       theme=pygame_menu.themes.THEME_SOLARIZED)

menu.add_button('Play', start_the_game)

while True:

    screen.blit(bgImg, (0, 0))

    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

    if menu.is_enabled():
        menu.update(events)
        menu.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
```

there is [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOXDk.png) of this code on website

If you did not understand something, then write, I will explain everything to you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844903/how-to-run-python-script-in-html

Comment: Briefly: it takes significant effort (as well as actual web hosting where you can use the server, not just something like github.io) to do that, and using a Python GUI framework (like Pygame) is right out. It would probably be easier to rewrite your program in JS so it can just run locally in the browser.