# How to execute python on web by clicking button

Tags: python, html, css

I created Form using html and css. I created python program that saves the data from user input. **BUT** I want to execute python program by clicking the button below the form on webpage.
***But I don't want to develop the design of form using python but with html and css, and I want to use python for data saving only by clicking the form button***

I tried due to saving the data from user input was easier in python and I don't know to execute python by clicking button on web

Comment: Try looking at [How can I run a Python Script in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844903/how-can-i-run-a-python-script-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into `PyScript`, I think it might do what you need.

Website: [`https://pyscript.net/`](https://pyscript.net/)

Docs: [`https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/`](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/)

But a fair warning before you do, it will slow down your webpage considerably, I would advise against implementing the form alongside other content that users may want to view even without submitting the form.