# Are semicolons mandatory in javascript statements?

Tags: javascript

I want to know, is this legal?

```
function test()
{
    alert ("hello")
    $("#loading").show();
}
```

Or should I write this instead:

```
function test()
{
    alert ("hello");
    $("#loading").show();
}
```

Are semicolons optional in JavaScript? Because I saw this in a forum:

> No, semicolons are usually optional in JavaScript (Google for ASI / automatic semicolon insertion). Using them makes the code look much cleaner though and ASI is a horrible mis-feature (at least in my opinion).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219541/what-is-the-difference-between-semicolons-in-javascript-and-in-python/7219549#7219549 and other answers to the question

Comment: Your two statements both have semicolons - neither are different.

Comment: @Nightfirecat - They didn't originally, looks like NullUserException's edit put the semi-colon back in. Edit: but then removed it again!

Comment: @Nightfirecat  . sorry i updated it

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Semicolons are not always mandatory, but I would always recommend using them. See the [ECMAScript spec](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9) for the rules on automatic semicolon insertion:

> Certain ECMAScript statements (empty statement, variable statement,
>   expression statement, do-while statement, continue statement, break
>   statement, return statement, and throw statement) must be terminated
>   with semicolons. Such semicolons may always appear explicitly in the
>   source text. For convenience, however, such semicolons may be omitted
>   from the source text in certain situations. These situations are
>   described by saying that semicolons are automatically inserted into
>   the source code token stream in those situations.

**Update** (to explain further)

Perhaps the most common situation used to show why automatic semicolon insertion can be bad is that touched on by @sissonb in another answer. Consider the following:

```
function something(a, b) {
    return
    a + b;
}
```

What you may be expecting is for the new-line to be ignored, and the code interpreted as:

```
function something(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Unfortunately, automatic semicolon insertion comes into play, and the code is actually interpreted like this:

```
function something(a, b) {
    return;
    a + b;
}
```

And an empty `return` statement means the function returns `undefined`. So instead of a nice sum of the two argument, you get `undefined` and potentially end up very confused as to where you've gone wrong! Which is why I completely agree with the statement in your question that automatic semicolon insertion is a horrible misfeature.

- [Example (returns `undefined` because of ASI).](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/6wqjq/)
- [Example (returns expected result).](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/6wqjq/1/)

Comment: One sensible exception would be a one-liner callback: `ar.sort(function(a, b) { return f(a) - f(b) })`

Answer (score 0):

Semicolons are not mandatory. They are automatically added at the end of a line if it is missing which actually causes this code to return undefined.

```
return
{
   text:"hello"
}
```