# Error when using argv

Tags: python, syntax-error, argv

I'm learning Python using [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/). It is very good and efficient but at one point I had a  crash. I've searched the web but could not find an answer.
Here is my question:

One of the exercises tell to do this:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv
```

and then it proceeds to doing things that I do understand:

```
print "we are going to erase %r." % filename
print "if you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "if you do want that, hit RETURN."

raw_input("?")

print "opening the file..." 
target = open(filename, 'w')
```

What does the first part mean?

P.S. the error I get is:

> syntaxError Unexpected character  after line continuation character

Comment: Please provide full error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
script, filename = argv
```

This is [unpacking the sequence](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) `argv`. The first element goes into `script`, and the second element goes into `filename`. In general, this can be done with any iterable, as long as there exactly as many variables on the left-hand-side as are items in the iterable on the right-hand-side.

The code you show seems ok, I don't know why you are getting a syntax-error there.

Comment: Exactly, the only problem was that the user was wrong (me). I interpreted what you said there as write in the script. Totally wrong ofcours. I had to write it on the commandline. Thanks tough for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`Unexpected character after line continuation character` means that you have split a command in two lines using the continuation character `\` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python)) but added some characters (e.g. a white space) after it.

But I do not see any `\` in your code...

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine, put the code in the example in the codefile.py and pass a dummydata file to it:

```
$ python codefile.py dummydatafile.txt 
 We're going to erase 'test1.txt'.
 If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C).
 If you do want that, hit RETURN.
 ?
 Opening the file...
 Truncating the file. Goodbye!
 Now I'm going to ask you for three lines.
 line 1: 
 line 2: 
 line 3: 
 I'm going to write these to the file.
 And finally, we close it.
$
```

This should solve your problem