# split the code with big variable names over two lines in python

Tags: python, coding-style

I want to split python code over two lines, my code is something similar to:

```
if long_named_three_d_array[first_dimension][second_dimension][third_dimension] == somevalue:
    //dosomething
```

I want to split above if condition over two lines.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use smaller variables instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python

Comment: @JoshBleecherSnyder: I have already looked at it. That does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the line break continuation character, `\`.

```
if long_named_three_d_array[first_dimension] \
    [second_dimension]\
    [third_dimension] == somevalue:
# Rest of code here, obviously properly indented in for the if.
```

Comment: thanks, I am looking for somehting similar, but it is not working for me. Can you confirm again.

Comment: @hrishikeshp19 Make sure you don't have any trailing whitespace after the \ character.

Comment: The "trailing slash" line continuation is evil because 1) any whitespace after the slash will break it, as @MichaelAnderson has noted, and also 2) any **comments** after the slash will break it. This is why Python Style Guide, PEP 8, recommends that you don't use the backslash syntax for line continuation.

Comment: The if expression can be put into brackets instead. Bracketed expressions can be broken into multiple lines without the use of backslashes.

Comment: @yak:  I agree with you and Li-aung Yip.  The backslash *is* another way to do it, but bracketing the LHS is the preferred way.

Answer (score 5):

In Python, the LHS can be bracketed.

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a[1] = {}
>>> a[1][2] = {}
>>> (a[1][2]
... [3]) = ''
>>> a
{1: {2: {3: ''}}}
>>> (b) = 2
>>> b
2
```

This means you can write your line as

```
if (long_named_three_d_array[first_dimension] 
    [second_dimension]
    [third_dimension] ) == somevalue:
# Rest of code here, obviously properly indented in for the if.
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use a temporary variable:

```
tmp = long_named_three_d_array[first_dimension][second_dimension][third_dimension] 
if tmp == somevalue:
    //dosomething
```

though shorter, yet descriptive variable identifiers would be a better choice if that's possible.