# Syntax error in Python regexp

Tags: python, syntax-error

When I started writing one function, i got Syntax error. I tried execute line at REPL - and it's worked. But i want to do it at IDE. Can somebody help me?

My code:

```
def sentence_splitter(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        input_str = f.read()
        period_indexes = get_periods(input_str)
        for el in period_indexes:
            sub_str = input_str[el - 14:el + 14]
            if not re.search(r'\.\s+[A-Za-z]{1,3}\w+', sub_str) and # Error here
            re.search(r'\.\d+', sub_str) and
            re.search(r'\.\s+[a-z]+', sub_str) and
            re.search(r'([A-Za-z\.]+\.\w+){1,50}', sub_str) and
            re.search(r'\w+\.[\.,]+', s):
                pass
```

Comment: You need a colon `:` after an `if` statement. Is that missing or just an error from copying your code?

Comment: it's not end of if statement. I have six re.search() lines in my condition

Comment: @Absolut Well how do you know that it's not in one of those?

Comment: Because my IDE indicate this line. Alone or with other functions in condition - anyway.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code, then?

Comment: Regardless of where the error is, that code has a weird structure. It would be much better form to have an array of regexps, and iterate through it as long as there is a match/not a match (you have a not in your expression, but it only applies to the first regexp- can't tell if this is a mistake or intentional on your part).

Comment: try to add parentheses around the multiline-if-condition: `if (stuff \n more stuff):`

Comment: @bitgarden, I agree, but i'm so newbie.

Comment: @ago, addinional parentheses solved my problem) thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parentheses around your if statement:

```
def sentence_splitter(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        input_str = f.read()
        period_indexes = get_periods(input_str)
        for el in period_indexes:
            sub_str = input_str[el - 14:el + 14]
            if not (re.search(r'\.\s+[A-Za-z]{1,3}\w+', sub_str) and # Error here
            re.search(r'\.\d+', sub_str) and
            re.search(r'\.\s+[a-z]+', sub_str) and
            re.search(r'([A-Za-z\.]+\.\w+){1,50}', sub_str) and
            re.search(r'\w+\.[\.,]+', s)):
                pass
```

Technically backslashes will work, but parentheses are more Pythonic, see PEP8: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length

Comment: It depends if you want the `not` to apply to the whole statement or just one condition. `not (1==1 and 1==2)` is true, but `(not 1==1 and 1==2)` is false.

Comment: Don't tell me! ;-) Maybe you want to add this explanation to your answer, after all, the default behaviour if they were all on one line would be that the `not` applies only to the first term. I.e., you fixed the error (+1) but also changed (fixed?) the condition.

Answer (score 2):

Your conditional spans multiple lines. You need to add the line continuation character `\`.

```
if not re.search(r'\.\s+[A-Za-z]{1,3}\w+', sub_str) and \
            re.search(r'\.\d+', sub_str) and \
            re.search(r'\.\s+[a-z]+', sub_str) and \
            re.search(r'([A-Za-z\.]+\.\w+){1,50}', sub_str) and \
            re.search(r'\w+\.[\.,]+', s):
```

Further information about this is available in [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53180/189134).

One note specific to your code:

```
re.search(r'\w+\.[\.,]+', s)
                          ^---- This variable is not assigned 
                                (likely should be sub_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your last regexp:

```
re.search(r'\w+\.[\.,]+', s)
```

You perform a search on `s`, which is not defined. All the other regexps perform a search on `substr`, which is probably what you want. That would raise a `NameError` though, not a `SyntaxError`.

Additionally, you probably want to refactor your code to make it easier to read, as explained in my comment to your question.