# Pythonic way to split math calculations

Tags: python

I use the ninja-ide and I find amazing the way it can complain about everything (yellow undertext line everywhere) because I think its a way to improve my coding to make it more standard.

However, since it does also complain about the length of the line of code (which of course makes a lot of sense, since no one likes to scroll horizontally to read the code), I've got stuck to this problem.

Lets say this line:

```
 v1, v2 = np.sum(((b1 - m1) ** 2) * p1) / q1, np.sum(((b2 - m2) ** 2) * p2) / q2
```

It does have 81 characters including the spaces, **in this case** I could split it like this:

```
    v1 = np.sum(((b1 - m1) ** 2) * p1) / q1
    v2 = np.sum(((b2 - m2) ** 2) * p2) / q2
```

But that doesn't feel much pythonic and there is also another problem:

What if there wasn't the comma?  I mean how could I split something like this:

```
   v2 = np.sum(((b1 - m1) ** 2 * np.sum(((b2 - np.sum(((b2 - m2) ** 2) * p2) / q2) ** 2) * p2) / q2) * p1)
```

*This above doesn't have any sense mathematically wise, it's just to explain what I meant.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I do a line break (line continuation) in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I disagree, there is much more to this question than a simple line break

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A backslash can be used to split long lines.

Where you split it is up to you, but the above line could be reworked as such:

```
v2 = np.sum(((b1 - m1) ** 2 * \
        np.sum(((b2 - np.sum(((b2 - m2) ** 2) * p2) / q2) ** 2) * p2) \
                                                                / q2) * p1)
```

I'd first try to reduce the code some other way (e.g. renaming variables, using other modules, altering the order of operations).

---

@user2357112 correctly notes that you don't need the backslash when splitting code inside unmatched parentheses, brackets, or braces, so the above code could also look like this:

```
v2 = np.sum(((b1 - m1) ** 2 *
        np.sum(((b2 - np.sum(((b2 - m2) ** 2) * p2) / q2) ** 2) * p2)
                                                                / q2) * p1)
```

From [PEP 8's Maximum Line Length](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length):

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied
>   line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines
>   can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in
>   parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash
>   for line continuation.

Comment: You don't actually need the backslash. Newlines inside unmatched parentheses, brackets, or braces are ignored.

Comment: @user2357112: Good point. I still use them for every line break so as not to worry whether there's an enclosing (/[/{ to handle the line break for me.

Comment: If you break at semantically sensible locations, generally between the biggest "chunks" possible, it tends to be pretty obvious whether there are appropriate unmatched tokens around the break. PEP 8 recommends this implicit line continuation over semicolons.

Comment: @user2357112: Another great point. I guess it's time for me to clean up some of my code ;)

Answer (score 4):

Don't bother about `pythonic`-way. Bother about good reading, performance and extensibility of your code. I think below would good 'pythonic' :) solution:

```
formula = lambda b, m, p, q: np.sum(((b - m) ** 2) * p) / q
v1, v2 = formula(b1, m1, p1, q1), formula(b2, m2, p2, q2)
```

Advantage of this way is you can use `formula` many times. And you get shortest string.