# New line on Python

Tags: python

```
while (0 > ship_row_1_1 or ship_row_1_1 > 9) or (0 > ship_row_1_2 or ship_row_1_2 > 9)\n
or(0 > ship_col_1_1 or ship_col_1_1 > 9) or (0 > ship_col_1_2 or ship_col_1_2 > 9):
```

I'm using python 2.7.6 and ran into an error I'm unsure of. This line was to long and I was having to side scroll to view the end so I tried adding the '\n' which I thought would let me continue the code on the next line. The problem is I get the error: 
"There's an error in your program: unexpected character after line continuation character"

There's no space or anything after the '\n' so I'm unsure why I'm getting this error.

I'm a beginner so any help is appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I do a line break (line continuation) in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python)

Comment: Try your best to avoid having to use `\\` in python to have multiple line operations

Comment: Through to break a line use \ or parentheses `(` `)`,  But Python Also provides `any()` and `all()` functions to write conditional expression nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply add a `\` and not a `\n` as follows:

#### Simple example

```
def say_hi():
    while True\
        and 1==1\
        and 2==2:
        print 'hello'
```

#### Your Case

```
while (0 > ship_row_1_1 or ship_row_1_1 > 9) or (0 > ship_row_1_2 or ship_row_1_2 > 9)\
or(0 > ship_col_1_1 or ship_col_1_1 > 9) or (0 > ship_col_1_2 or ship_col_1_2 > 9):
```

Comment: @user3485148, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thanks

Comment: Sshashank single `#` heading looks too large, try with three `###`  I think you will better like.

Comment: @Grijesh, Ah, I didn't even know that. Thank you very much

Comment: yes I knew you are new at SO. I never read [markdown notes](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) Whenver I see a nicely formatted answer (that I can't do) I just ckick on edit to see how answer is written. :)

Answer (score 1):

'\n' is the newline character. It only has meaning inside strings, where it splits the line. If you want to continue a line of code, just use a single '\'. The error is saying that Python doesn't know what to do with the 'n' it found *after* you told it with the '\' that you were going to continue on the next line.