# Python read from file and remove non-ascii characters

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, utf

I have the following program that reads a file word by word and writes the word again to another file but without the non-ascii characters from the first file.

```
import unicodedata
import codecs
infile = codecs.open('d.txt','r',encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore')
outfile = codecs.open('d_parsed.txt','w',encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore')


for line in infile.readlines():
    for word in line.split():
        outfile.write(word+" ")
    outfile.write("\n")

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

The only problem that I am facing is that with this code it does not print a new line to the second file (d_parsed). Any clues??

Comment: Whats wrong with it. It works perfectly.

Comment: It does not do a new line as in outfile.write("\n")

Comment: It could appear that there is no `\n` at the end of each line if you are on Windows and the text editor with which you are viewing the file does not recognize `\n` as a line-separator.

Comment: As a side note: This code does not remove non-ASCII characters - it removes characters that can't be decoded with the `UTF-8` encoding.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`codecs.open()` doesn't support universal newlines e.g., it doesn't translate `\r\n` to `\n` while reading on Windows.

Use `io.open()` instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import io

with io.open('d.txt','r',encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore') as infile, \
     io.open('d_parsed.txt','w',encoding='ascii',errors='ignore') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        print(*line.split(), file=outfile)
```

btw, if you want to remove non-ascii characters, you should use `ascii` instead of `utf-8`.

If the input encoding is compatible with ascii (such as utf-8) then you could open the file in binary mode and use `bytes.translate()` to remove non-ascii characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
nonascii = bytearray(range(0x80, 0x100))
with open('d.txt','rb') as infile, open('d_parsed.txt','wb') as outfile:
    for line in infile: # b'\n'-separated lines (Linux, OSX, Windows)
        outfile.write(line.translate(None, nonascii))
```

It doesn't normalize whitespace like the first code example.

Comment: `bytes.translate()`  - very nice

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs for `codecs.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html):

> **Note:** Files are always opened in binary mode, even if no binary mode was specified. This is done to avoid data loss due to encodings using 8-bit values. This means that no automatic conversion of '\n' is done on reading and writing.

I presume you're using Windows, where the newline sequence is actually `'\r\n'`. A file opened in text mode will do the conversion from `\n` to `\r\n` automatically, but that doesn't happen with `codecs.open`.

Simply write `"\r\n"` instead of `"\n"` and it should work fine, at least on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

use codecs to open the csv file and then you can avoid the non-ascii characters

```
 import codecs   
reader = codecs.open("example.csv",'r', encoding='ascii', errors='ignore')
    for reading in reader:
        print (reader)
```