# Python File Writing Format Issue

Tags: python-3.x

**The Code**

```
def rainfallInInches():
file_object = open('rainfalls.txt')
list_of_cities = []
list_of_rainfall_inches = []

for line in file_object:
    cut_up_line = line.split()
    city = cut_up_line[0]
    rainfall_mm = int(line[len(line) - 3:])
    rainfall_inches = rainfall_mm / 25.4
    list_of_cities.append(city)
    list_of_rainfall_inches.append(rainfall_inches)

inch_index = 0
desired_file = open("rainfallInInches.txt", "w")
for city in list_of_cities:
    desired_file.writelines(str((city, "{0:0.2f}".format(list_of_rainfall_inches[inch_index]))))
    inch_index += 1
desired_file.close()
```

**rainfalls.txt**

> ```
> Manchester 37
> Portsmouth 9
> London 5
> Southampton 12
> Leeds 20
> Cardiff 42
> Birmingham 34
> Edinburgh 26
> Newcastle 11
> ```

**rainfallInInches.txt**
This is the unwanted output

> ('Manchester', '1.46')('Portsmouth', '0.35')('London',
>   '0.20')('Southampton', '0.47')('Leeds', '0.79')('Cardiff',
>   '1.65')('Birmingham', '1.34')('Edinburgh', '1.02')('Newcastle',
>   '0.43')

My program takes the data from 'rainfalls.txt' which has rainfall information in mm and converts the mm to inches then writes this new information into a new file 'rainfallInInches.txt'.

I've gotten this far except I can't figure out how to format 'rainfallInInches.txt' to make it look like 'rainfalls.txt'.

Bear in mind that I am a student, which you probably gathered by my hacky code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My program takes the data from 'rainfalls.txt' which has rainfall information in mm and converts the mm to inches then writes this new information into a new file 'rainfallInInches.txt'.

You could separate the parsing of the input file, the conversion from mm to inches, and the final formatting for writing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# read input
rainfall_data = [] # city, rainfall pairs
with open('rainfalls.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.strip(): # non-blank
            city, rainfall = line.split() # no comments in the input
            rainfall_data.append((city, float(rainfall)))

def mm_to_inches(mm):
    """Convert *mm* to inches."""
    return mm * 0.039370

# write output
with open('rainfallInInches.txt', 'w') as file:
    for city, rainfall_mm in rainfall_data:
        file.write("{city} {rainfall:.2f}\n".format(city=city,
            rainfall=mm_to_inches(rainfall_mm)))
```

#### [rainfallInInches.txt](http://ideone.com/wRl2ZF):

```
Manchester 1.46
Portsmouth 0.35
London 0.20
Southampton 0.47
Leeds 0.79
Cardiff 1.65
Birmingham 1.34
Edinburgh 1.02
Newcastle 0.43
```

If you feel confident that each step is correct in isolation then you could combine the steps:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def mm_to_inches(mm):
    """Convert *mm* to inches."""
    return mm * 0.039370

with open('rainfalls.txt') as input_file, \
     open('rainfallInInches.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if line.strip(): # non-blank
            city, rainfall_mm = line.split() # no comments
            output_file.write("{city} {rainfall:.2f}\n".format(city=city,
                rainfall=mm_to_inches(float(rainfall_mm))))
```

[It produces the same output](http://ideone.com/VfDdPo).

Comment: Thank you very much. I am spending some time now going over the code you wrote to make sure I fully comprehend it. It works great!

Answer (score 0):

First is better change your parser to split a string by space. With this you dont need a complex logic to take numbers.
After this, to print correctly, change your output to

```
 file.write("{} {0:0.02f}\n".format(city,list_of_rainfall_inches[inch_index] ))
```