# Comments in continuation lines

Tags: python, continuation

Say I have a multiline command:

```
if 2>1 \
 and 3>2:
    print True
```

In an `if` block, I can add a comment next to one of the conditions by using parentheses to wrap the lines:

```
if (2>1 #my comment
 and 3>2):
    print True
```

And, in fact, it is aligned with the recommened way of doing this by [PEP 8 guideline](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008#maximum-line-length):

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.

However, sometimes you need to use continuations. For example, [long, multiple with-statements cannot use implicit continuation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53200/1983854). Then, how can I add a comment next to a specific line? This does not work:

```
with open('a') as f1, #my comment\
 open('b') as f2:
    print True
```

More generally, is there a generic way to add a comment next to a specific continuation line?

Comment: Spyder tells me "invalid sytax" when I put your code in, and "unexpected character after line continuation character" when I put a `\` before the comment, so I'm guessing no, you can't do line comments with line continuation. I'm guessing that it has to do with trying to splice a comment into a statement, i.e. x = 2 + #comment# 3

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot. Find some extracts from [Python reference manual (3.4)](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/lexical_analysis.html):

> A comment starts with a hash character (#) that is not part of a
>   string literal, and ends at the end of the physical line.
>
> A line ending in a backslash cannot carry a comment
>
> A comment signifies the end of the logical line unless the implicit
>   line joining rules are invoked
>
> Implicit line joining : Expressions in parentheses, square brackets or
>   curly braces can be split over more than one physical line without
>   using backslashes
>
> Implicitly continued lines can carry comments

So the reference manual explicitly disallows to add a comment in an explicit continuation line.

Answer (score 5):

You can't have comments and backslash for line continuation on the same line. You need to use some other strategy.

The most basic would be to adjust the comment text to place it e.g. before the relevant section. You could also document your intentions without comments at all by refactoring the code returning the context into a function or method with a descriptive name.

Comment: Interesting!. I am accepting the other answer, since it provides some references. However, this one I will also use. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any solution except nesting the `with`:

```
with open('a.txt', 'w') as f1: #comment1
    with open('b.txt', 'w') as f2: #comment2
        print True
```

Comment: Obviously the with-statement is not "multiple" anymore.

Comment: This is a clever way to prevent the problem from happening. However, I am still curious about how to do this _using_ continuation lines.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine end-of-line comment (`#`) and line continuation (`\`) on the same line.

**I am not recommending this. --** However, sometimes you can masquerade your comment as a string:

```
with open(('a', '# COMMENT THIS')[0]) as f1, \
     open(('b', '# COMMENT THAT')[0]) as f2:
    print(f1, f2)
```