# How do I do line continuation with a long regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a long regex that I want to continue on to the next line, but everything I've tried gives me either an EOL or breaks the regex. I have already continued the line once within the parenthesis, and have read [How can I do a line break (line continuation)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation) among other things.

Working, but still too long:

```
REGEX = re.compile(
            r'\d\s+\d+\s+([A-Z0-9-]+)\s+([0-9]+.\d\(\d\)[A-Z0-9]+)\s+([a-zA-Z\d-]+)')
```

Wrong:

```
REGEX = re.compile(
            r'\d\s+\d+\s+([A-Z0-9-]+)\s+([0-9]+.\d\(\d\)[A-Z0-9]+
            )\s+([a-zA-Z\d-]+)')

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal


REGEX = re.compile(
            r'\d\s+\d+\s+([A-Z0-9-]+)\s+([0-9]+.\d\(\d\
                )[A-Z0-9]+)\s+([a-zA-Z\d-]+)')
    
sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis


REGEX = re.compile(
            r'\d\s+\d+\s+([A-Z0-9-]+)\s+( \
            [0-9]+.\d\(\d\)[A-Z0-9]+)\s+([a-zA-Z\d-]+)')

regex no longer works


REGEX = (re.compile(
            r'\d\s+\d+\s+([A-Z0-9-]+)\s+(
            [0-9]+.\d\(\d\)[A-Z0-9]+)\s+([a-zA-Z\d-]+)'))

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I have been able to shorten my regex so that this is no longer an issue, but I'm now interested to know how I might do line continuation with a long regex?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=verbose#re.VERBOSE

Comment: The problem with your search query was that you're thinking of this as continuing a line, and the answer you found is about "continuing a _logical_ line," which isn't what you need. The terminology to get the answer you needed was "continuing a multiline _string_."

Comment: I guess I perceived the regex to be distinct from a regular Python string. Though the `re.VERBOSE` answer is specific to a regex beyond making the regex a multiline string.

Comment: The only difference between a regex and the strings you usually work with is the `r` to denote a raw string. It's only there for convenience. You can use `r` with strings not intended as regexes (e.g. `r'C:\Users'`), and you can make regex strings without `r` (e.g. `'[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}'`).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you use the `re.VERBOSE` flag, you can split your regular expression up as much as you like to make it more readable:

```
pattern = r"""
    \d\s+
    \d+\s+
    ([A-Z0-9-]+)\s+
    ([0-9]+.\d\(\d\)[A-Z0-9]+)\s+
    ([a-zA-Z\d-]+)"""

REGEX = re.compile(pattern, re.VERBOSE)
```

This approach is explained in the excellent "Dive Into Python" book.
See "Verbose Regular Expressions".

Comment: I like that this keeps it within the regular expression rather than using concatenation.

Answer (score 7):

You can use multiple strings in multiple lines, and Python would concatenate them (as long as the multiple strings are between `(` and `)`) before sending to `re.compile`. Example -

```
REGEX = re.compile(r"\d\s+\d+\s+([A-Z0-9-]+)\s+([0-9]+.\d\(\d\)"
                   r"[A-Z0-9]+)\s+([a-zA-Z\d-]+)")
```

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
regex = re.compile(
    r'\d\s+\d+\s+([A-Z0-9-]+)\s+('
    r'[0-9]+.\d\(\d\)[A-Z0-9]+)\s+([a-zA-Z\d-]+)'
)
```