# Is there a way to format one line into multiple lines with continuation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a long line like this below in Python:

```
patterns = re.compile(r'(^/afs|^/pkg|^/bin|^/dev|^/etc|^/usr|^/usr2|^/sys|^/sbin|^/proc)')
```

And then I tried and changed it to this format below. However, it does not work as expected anymore:

```
patterns = re.compile(r'(^/afs|\
                         ^/pkg|\
                         ^/bin|\
                         ^/dev|\
                         ^/etc|\
                         ^/usr|\
                         ^/usr2|\
                         ^/sys|\
                         ^/sbin|\
                         ^/proc)')
```

I know Python is using indentation for syntax so probably this format would not work maybe? or is there a right way to format this in Python if there is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep everything in one single set of quotations you can use a docstring, that will remove the need for line breaks or multiple `r'^...'` symbols, i.e.

```
patterns = re.compile(r"""
                         ...
                        """)
```

As described in the following post: [How do I do line continuation with a long regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211404/how-do-i-do-line-continuation-with-a-long-regex)

I generally find this approach more readable.

Comment: Thank you! This sounds a good way for the format, but I guess I would still need "^", right? such as 
r"""
(^/afs|
^/pkg|
^/sbin)
"""
Otherwise, how would it know these regex patterns need to be at the beginning of the line?

Comment: @yuchit: Yes you still need the `^` characters which are part of the regex pattern itself.

Comment: @martineau Thank you! Yes, I also tried it out and can confirm ```^``` is still needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's very straightforward:

```py
patterns = re.compile(r'(^/afs|'
                      r'^/pkg|'
                      r'^/bin|'
                      r'^/dev|'
                      r'^/etc|'
                      r'^/usr|'
                      r'^/usr2|'
                      r'^/sys|'
                      r'^/sbin|'
                      r'^/proc)')
```

I recommend using a decent Python editor or IDE, as these will typically do this for you automatically. I happen to use PyCharm which does, but I'm sure VSCode, or other popular IDEs and code editors can do a good job at this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Python regular expressions have a verbose mode that lets you use a multi-line triple quote with comments.  Also note that `re.match` (as opposed to `re.search`) implies a `^` and the `/` doesn't need to be repeated.

You can add a leading `(?x)` to the pattern or use the [flags](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X) `re.VERBOSE` or its alias `re.X` to turn on verbose mode:

```py
import re

patterns = re.compile(r'''(?x)/(usr2|     # comments also supported
                               sbin|
                               proc|
                               afs|
                               pkg|       # better to put longer matches first
                               bin|
                               dev|
                               etc|
                               usr|       # if before /usr2, would match this first
                               sys)''')

for trial in ('/afs/blah','/usr2/blah'):
    print(patterns.match(trial))
```

Output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='/afs'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='/usr2'>
```

Also note that whitespace and comments are ignored in verbose mode, so if you have significant white space match it explicitly with `\s` or other escape codes.