# python invalid syntax everytime

Tags: python, syntax-error

My code always gives invalid syntax errors in different lines. I mean it is giving an error at line 143. Then when I clear that line. It gives the same error at another line. Even I get invalid syntax error at a line like:

```
print("======================================================================")
```

How can this be possible? Any ideas?
Thank you ^^

Comment: Please, post the exact error message and the lines where you get them

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472645/syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-on-valid-statement

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to know without seeing the whole code. However, be aware that  python has [implied line continuation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53180/279858) with parentheses and other brackets.

This can mean that errors can be *reported* on a different to that on which the true mistake has been made.

For example:

```
a = (3 * 4) + (3 * 2
print "Hello"
```

...gives the error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-1-53e17eda21df>", line 2
    print "Hello"
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is happening is that Python expects the first line to continue, e.g like:

```
a = (3 * 4) + (3 * 2
    + 100)
```

...which is completely valid syntax. However, it finds `print "Hello"` instead, which isn't a valid continuation of the statement inside the brackets.

Comment: When I read your answer, I was expecting it to end with something like "in other words, you're missing a parenthesis on a preceding line". While the answer accurately describes the situation, it may be a bit vague for the type of person who would ask this type of question. You might want to strengthen the answer by giving some practical advice, such as looking for a missing parenthesis, bracket or quote on a previous line.