# Backslash in c source file

Tags: c, video, hevc

I have follow code same as it is on different lines:

```
frame_rate = (float)
                ( ( ( frames * media_timescale) + \   //WHY???
                    ( media_duration >> 1 ) ) /
                 media_duration);
```

I am not understanding what is backslash doing in source file ?
Also to calculate the frame rate simply we can do as follow:

```
frame_rate = (float) ( (  frames * media_timescale) / media_duration);
```

Is there any specific intention to write first type of code?

Comment: That isn't a macro, so that \ is *pointless*. The code would be completely valid without it. I suspect someone sniped that code from what was at-one-time a macro, and just left it as-is.

Comment: The `+ (media_duration >> 1)` is intended to round the value up, assuming that you convert the result to an `int` at some point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a line-continuation escape. It means the compiler will consider the next line as a part of the current line.

It makes the code you show in practice being

```
frame_rate = (float)
                ( ( ( frames * media_timescale) + ( media_duration >> 1 ) ) /
                 media_duration);
```

There's no real need for it in this case though, except as maybe some style-guide followed by the author had it as a requirement.

Line continuation is needed to define "multi-line" macros, and are also often used for long strings. But besides those places, it serves no real purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Backslash is used to split a long line into 2 shorter lines, without signifying an end of the statement. This is usually done when a single line statement might be too long to read.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash is a **line continuation**. It makes no difference other than for readability purposes (80 characters per line is usually the recommended limit for most style guides).

See: [How can I do a line break (line continuation) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python)

Comment: I've removed the rather blatant copy of someone else's example. When you want to reference someone else's work, please use proper quoting and attribution, and only *sparingly to support your own words*.

Comment: And I don't see how a link to a Python post is relevant to a question about C. Python's logical line rules differ in some crucial areas from those in C.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anybody could describe this better than the standard. Hence, according to [C11/section 5.1.1.2p1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2), which summarises the stages of translation (*compilation*, if you will) which occur when you invoke your compiler:

> 2. Each instance of a backslash character (`\`) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. A source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place.

Thus, from your example, the first line ends up effectively *spliced* (joined) with the second due to the combination of the backslash and newline.

Comment: According to this section, shoudn't not only macro definitions, but also lines of code broken in two lines by the combination of backslash and newline characters, such as `puts("Single" \ "Line");`, be translated by the preprocessor into `puts("Single" "Line");` and then `puts("Single Line");` when the adjacent strings are concatenated?

Comment: @dandev486 your understanding seems mostly correct; line splice elimination occurs long before preprocessing.

Comment: I see, so it actually happens prior to the preprocessing phase, thanks for the clarification! I thought that all steps until macro replacements were performed by the preprocessor.

Comment: @dandev486 yes, line splice elimination is in translation phase 2 (hence the 2 at the start of the quote from the standard). Translation phase 3 is a bit of tokenization. Translation phase 4 is where preprocessing proper begins.