# single backslash at the end of a line in c

Tags: c, gcc

```
    #define THREAD_TYPE(thread)                         \
    typedef struct                                      \
    {                                                   \
      pthread_t pthread;                                \
      int err;                                          \
    }t;
```

> what is the purpose of \ in the above macro?

Comment: Looks like a macro. Only that the `#define` is missing.

Comment: I think in your original code , you will find a  #define

Comment: Oops my bad! #define is there. I will edit it rightaway.

Comment: Also [Backslash in C source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42109557).