# how Backslash \ joins printf strings when written on separate lines in C?

Tags: c, printf, backslash

Using Dev C++ I was doing some fun with C and got this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
printf("Hello
      world" );
}
```

^^^^ here I thought output would be like "Hello (with spaces) World" but 
Errors :

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Dev C++ Programs\helloWorldDk.c In function 'main':
5   10  C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Dev C++ Programs\helloWorldDk.c [Warning] missing terminating " character
5   3   C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Dev C++ Programs\helloWorldDk.c [Error] missing terminating " character
6   8   C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Dev C++ Programs\helloWorldDk.c [Warning] missing terminating " character
6   1   C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Dev C++ Programs\helloWorldDk.c [Error] missing terminating " character
6   1   C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Dev C++ Programs\helloWorldDk.c [Error] 'world' undeclared (first use in this function)
6   1   C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Dev C++ Programs\helloWorldDk.c [Note] each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
7   1   C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Dev C++ Programs\helloWorldDk.c [Error] expected ')' before '}' token
7   1   C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Dev C++ Programs\helloWorldDk.c [Error] expected ';' before '}' token
```

but when i added a \ it worked :

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{ 
printf("Hello \ 
   World" );
}
```

Without any warnings and errors.
What Magic of '\' is this ?
And do any other soccery exists , please let me know .

Comment: Your first code snippet is missing the last `}`, and your second one is missing a `"`. Please copy your code exactly as it is for any question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backslash in c source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42109557/backslash-in-c-source-file)

Comment: it's basically "Hello \\n World"

Comment: @ThomasJager , yeah missed them to write here . Edited the Question.

Comment: @Jacob Thank you, Jacob learned a new thing today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The backslash has many special meanings, e.g. escape sequences to  represent special characters.

But the special meaning you found is the one of `\` immediatly followed by a newline; which is "ignore me and the newline". For the compiler this solves the problem of encountering a newline in the middle of a string.

Answer (score 0):

The `C` pre-processor will [line splice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Phases), so one could have written,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello\n"
        "World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Arguably nicer syntax with long strings. Note that the [maximum length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488616/why-is-max-length-of-c-string-literal-different-from-max-char) is still enforced. From a theoretical point-of-view, the `C` pre-processor is a language unto itself, see [a discussion on Turing-completeness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10526117/2472827). For a practical example, [x-macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) are very useful in some cases.