# How to convert numbers represented as characters for short into numeric in Python

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a column in my data frame which has values like '3.456B' which actually stands for 3.456 Billion (and similar notation for Million). How to convert this string form to correct numeric representation?

This shows the data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
data_csv = pd.read_csv('https://biz.yahoo.com/p/csv/422conameu.csv')
data_csv
```

This is a sample value:

```
data_csv['Market Cap'][0]
type(data_csv['Market Cap'][0])
```

I tried this:

```
data_csv.loc[data_csv['Market Cap'].str.contains('B'), 'Market Cap'] = data_csv['Market Cap'].str.replace('B', '').astype(float).fillna(0.0)
data_csv
```

But unfortunately there are also values with 'M' at the end which denotes Millions. It returns error as follows:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 6.46M
```

How can I replace both B and M with appropriate values in this column? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming all entries have a letter at the end, you can do this:

```
d = {'K': 1000, 'M': 1000000, 'B': 1000000000}
df.loc[:, 'Market Cap'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Market Cap'].str[:-1]) * \
    df['Market Cap'].str[-1].replace(d)
```

This converts everything but the last character into a numeric value, then multiplies it by the number equivalent to the letter in the last character.

Comment: The problem is that B and M come after the decimal point in most cases. The zeros coming after decimal don't count right?

Comment: Does this work for you? I am getting: 'SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character'.

Comment: Try it again now - there were a few spaces that crept in after the \.

Comment: Thank you. This solves the problem. Could you share some resource which explains how '\'  works? I am not familiar with its usage.

Comment: Sure!  Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python

Answer (score 5):

I'd use a dictionary to replace the strings then evaluate as float.

```
mapping = dict(K='E3', M='E6', B='E9')

df['Market Cap'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Market Cap'].replace(mapping, regex=True))
```

Answer (score 2):

First extract units as last character in strings. Then convert values without units to floats and multiply where needed:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Market Cap':['6.46M','2.25B','0.23B']})
units = df['Market Cap'].str[-1]
df['Market Cap'] = df['Market Cap'].str[:-1].astype(float)
df.loc[units=='M','Market Cap'] *= 0.001
#    Market Cap
# 0     0.00646
# 1     2.25000
# 2     0.23000
```

Now everything is in billions.