# Where is "object of type 'int' has no len()" coming from?

Tags: python

```
randNum = random.randrange (1,3)
    NameMale = ['Noah']
    NameFemale = ['Alyna']
    Job = ['Accountant'] 
    Age = random.randrange (18,81)
    Gender = ['Male', 'Female']
    Company = ['State Farm']
    Event = ['A drunk driver hit me head-on']
    if randNum == 1:
        print ("Hi. I'm {}. I'm {} years old, and I was a(n) {} at {}. That is, until everything changed. One day, {}.").format((random.choice(NameMale)),(random.choice(Age)),(random.choice(Job)),(random.choice(Company)),(random.choice(Event)))
```

## error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Scenario Generator.py", line 14, in <module>
    print ("Hi. I'm {}. I'm {} years old, and I was a(n) {} at {}. That is, until everything changed. One day, {}.").format((random.choice(NameMale)),(random.choice(Age)),(random.choice(Job)),(random.choice(Company)),(random.choice(Event)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 275, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

What does this mean, where is it coming from, and how can I solve it?

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python to make the print statement appear on multiple rows for readability.

Answer (score 2):

The call `random.randrange(18, 81)` returns an integer and not a sequence. 
So the call to `random.choice(Age)` will throw an error.

Comment: If you want the age to be between 18 and 18, make Age=range (18,81) then you can call choice(age)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the error came from module named `random.py` when you call function `random.choice(Age)`

The parameter of `random.choice()` have to be a `sequence` not an `integer`.

Check your `Age` variable one more time

Answer (score 0):

Change Age = random.randrange (18,81)
to
Age = [random.randrange (18,81)]

random.randrage returns number and choice expects sequence.