# Python with statement break line without backslash

Tags: python

How can I break this line without using "\"?

```
with mock.patch('six.moves.builtins.open', mock.mock_open()), mock.patch('my_module.yaml.safe_load') as mock_yaml:
    #do something
```

I tried with parenthesis but it complains with SyntaxError about the "as"

```
with (mock.patch('six.moves.builtins.open', mock.mock_open()),
    mock.patch('my_module.yaml.safe_load') as mock_yaml):
    #do something
```

Comment: Is it in a file or in _Python_ console?

Comment: Quoting PEP-8: [*"long, multiple with-statements cannot use implicit continuation, so backslashes are acceptable "*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53200/3001761).

Comment: in a file, I execute the file from the console.

Comment: @user2357112 That doesn't seem to be a very good duplicate... the answers all focus on the "integrated comments" part of that question, which are not relevant to this one.

Comment: @glibdud: It's the same issue. Inline comments stop you from using backslash continuation, so the answers are all about splitting the `with` across lines without backslashes.

Comment: @user2357112 But without the need for comments, the answer to this one appears to be "PEP8 recommends you just stick with the backslash".

Comment: If you're using this in multiple places, another approach would be to wrap the nested `with`s in another context manager using [`@contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager).

Answer (score 0):

Breaking it inside a set of parentheses, but without the parentheses around `mock.patch(....)`, should work according to the [PEP8 Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), due to implied line continuation between parentheses:

```
with mock.patch('six.moves.builtins.open', 
                mock.mock_open()), mock.patch('my_module.yaml.safe_load') as mock_yaml:
```

The other option is similar to your second suggestion, but with the closing parentheses moved to before the `as`:

```
with (mock.patch('six.moves.builtins.open', mock.mock_open()), 
      mock.patch('my_module.yaml.safe_load')) as mock_yaml:
```

Comment: Can you show exactly what you mean?

Comment: I think you cannot break after the `,` but you could break inside the parentheses.

Comment: Can you check if that works?  I think there may be a different set of parentheses missing - I've added them where I *think* they should go, but I may be wrong.  Happy to edit my answer if I am.

Comment: I think you screwed up your parentheses; that's not how `mock.patch` works.

Comment: You've changed the meaning of the statement with those parens. As written by the OP, the `as mock_yaml` belongs only to the second `mock.patch()`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I did screw that one up.  Fixed it, to conform with PEP8.

Comment: That works to shorten the longest line, but it kind of hurts readability.

Comment: It does.  It seemed much more straightforward when I started typing the answer.  I should really consider going to bed.

Comment: I guess, in this case, using the backslash is probably the best bet, given the funny placement of parentheses

Comment: I've made an edit, similar to your problematic try, moving the parentheses to before the as.  I believe that should work - can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, that works and also splitting the strings but it's a bit unreadable... 

I will use backslash as it is accepted in these cases... Thank you!

Comment: Cool cool.  I learnt something anyway :)