# computing a distance matrix without using scipy python

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, matrix-multiplication

I want to understand a specific part of code which computes a distance matrix between two 2d. matrices.

the smarter and easiest way to do it is by using scipy like this code

```
import scipy
import scipy.spatial

D = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(X_norm, X_norm)
```

​but there is an alternative way which i have a problem with to understand. It is this one

```
Dalt = np.sqrt(((X_norm ** 2).sum(axis=1).reshape((1, len(X_norm))) \
      + (X_norm ** 2).sum(axis=1).reshape((len(X_norm), 1)) \
      - 2 * numpy.dot(X_norm, X_norm.T)) + 1e-7)

print(((Dalt - D) ** 2).mean())
```

What I actually do not understand is the last part when he finally add this part

```
+ le-7)
```

Comment: Backslash is the way to continue the expression on the next line without having an indentation error

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/53162/3729797

Comment: Thankx alot for you comment

Comment: @AhmedMohamed, that `+ 1e-7` actually causes a small error and is not necessary. I'm not sure why the one who created that added that value. Usually, adding very small values is used to prevent computational errors however I could not identify the error they're trying to avoid in this case

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `artificial-intelligence` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed).