# Python Syntax for Assigning Multiple Variables Across Multiple Lines

Tags: python

I'm am trying to assign values to multiple variables in one statement, but I cannot figure out if there is a nice syntax to split it across multiple lines.

```
# This is the long version I don't want
a, b, c, d = tf.constant(1, name='constant_a'), tf.constant(2, name='constant_b'), tf.constant(3, name='constant_c'), tf.constant(4, name='constant_d')

# Does something like this exist?
a, b, c, d = tf.constant(1, name='constant_a'), /
             tf.constant(2, name='constant_b'), /
             tf.constant(3, name='constant_c'), /
             tf.constant(4, name='constant_d')
```

Is there a nice, Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: What is your motivation for that? (except curiosity?)
What is the problem with simply:

```python
a = tf.constant(..)
...
d = tf.constant(..)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were thinking of backslash ([line continuation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53162/4518341)).

```
a, b, c, d = tf.constant(1, name='constant_a'), \
             tf.constant(2, name='constant_b'), \
             tf.constant(3, name='constant_c'), \
             tf.constant(4, name='constant_d')
```

This works, but it's ugly. Better to use a tuple/list like in [Joseph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61189890/4518341), or better yet a comprehension like in [Josh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61189928/4518341).

Comment: Yes I was! Thanks, I could have sworn that syntax existed but I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't work. I happen to agree it's ugly, I just wanted confirmation the line continuation syntax worked in assigning multiple variables. Silly mistake in the end, cheers for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap what you have in parenthesis.

```
a, b, c, d = (tf.constant(1, name='constant_a'), 
              tf.constant(2, name='constant_b'), 
              tf.constant(3, name='constant_c'),
              tf.constant(4, name='constant_d'))
```

Comment: might as well use square brackets since they stand out more from the parentheses of the function calls, and there's no real difference between a list and a tuple in this context. BTW welcome to SO!

Comment: You're right that using square brackets looks a bit more Pythonic as it were. I chose the tuple because I found that it is ~1.3x faster than using a list in this context, although I need to think on why... The calculation time is so small for both it _really_ doesn't matter though. Thanks for the welcome! I'm happy to finally contribute as I'm a long-time beneficiary of the site.

Comment: I could have sworn I read that lists behave as well as tuples in one-off unpackings like this, but I can't find it anymore. But yeah it makes sense that tuples perform better. Also I just noticed the parens around the names, `(a, b, c, d)` -- those aren't necessary.

Comment: You're right about the unnecessary parenthesis. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's more readable/Pythonic, but this is the most succinct!

```
a, b, c, d = [tf.constant(i, name='constant_' + x) for i, x in zip(range(1, 5), 'abcd')]
```