# TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str' in string creation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting the above mentioned error when running:

```
def Decode(iList):
    IssuerList = ["Dummy","enRoute","JCB","Diner's Club","Visa"
                  ,"Master Card","Union Pay","Petroleum"]
    TypeList = ["Debit account", "Credit account"]
    for istr in iList:
        ostr = istr + ": Was issued by " + IssuerList[int(istr[1])] + " in 20"
        + istr[2:4] + ". The card expires on " + istr[4:6] + "/" + istr[6:8]
        + ". The card is linked to a " + TypeList[int(istr[8])]
        + " with the account number: " + istr[8:]
        WriteFile(ostr)



File "", line 24, in Decode
    + istr[2:4] + ". The card expires on " + istr[4:6] + "/" + istr[6:8]
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

Have tried str() on the bad line but no luck.

Comment: How do you call `Decode()` ? Meaning, what exactly is `iList` ? Additionally, `format()` would make this much much cleaner.

Comment: What is the content of ``iList`` ?

Comment: The line where you assign `ostr` is a complete statement by itself - there's nothing to tell Python that you intended the statement to continue for multiple lines.  So the next line gets interpreted as a statement starting with `+ <a string>`, which is nonsense.  Multiple options here: parenthesize the entire expression being assigned to `ostr`, use trailing `+`s instead of leading so that the lines are individually incomplete, end lines with backslashes, probably others.

Comment: iList contains string like this `0719220408435222`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a valid, complete line of Python

```
    ostr = istr + ": Was issued by " + IssuerList[int(istr[1])] + " in 20"
```

Then another line starting with a unary +, which isn't a valid statement applied to a string.

```
    + istr[2:4] + ". The card expires on " + istr[4:6] + "/" + istr[6:8]
```

See [How can I do a line continuation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python) for the options to continue an expression over more than one line.

The practice recommended in the [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#should-a-line-break-before-or-after-a-binary-operator) is to use parenthesis and break before the operator.

```
def Decode(iList):
    IssuerList = ["Dummy","enRoute","JCB","Diner's Club","Visa"
                  ,"Master Card","Union Pay","Petroleum"]
    TypeList = ["Debit account", "Credit account"]
    for istr in iList:
        ostr = (istr + ": Was issued by " + IssuerList[int(istr[1])] + " in 20"
            + istr[2:4] + ". The card expires on " + istr[4:6] + "/" + istr[6:8]
            + ". The card is linked to a " + TypeList[int(istr[8])]
            + " with the account number: " + istr[8:])
        WriteFile(ostr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that python knows that you want to carry the expression to the next line. In this case it does not know that unless you tell it using a `\` at the end of the line or enclose the expression in `()`. Basically some way to indicate that the seemingly completed expression is not complete and continues on the next line.

This:

```py
        ostr = istr + ": Was issued by " + IssuerList[int(istr[1])] + " in 20"
        + istr[2:4] + ". The card expires on " + istr[4:6] + "/" + istr[6:8]
        + ". The card is linked to a " + TypeList[int(istr[8])]
        + " with the account number: " + istr[8:]
```

should be:

```py
        ostr = istr + ": Was issued by " + IssuerList[int(istr[1])] + " in 20" \
               + istr[2:4] + ". The card expires on " + istr[4:6] + "/" + istr[6:8] \
               + ". The card is linked to a " + TypeList[int(istr[8])] \
               + " with the account number: " + istr[8:]
```

or:

```py
        ostr = (istr + ": Was issued by " + IssuerList[int(istr[1])] + " in 20" 
                + istr[2:4] + ". The card expires on " + istr[4:6] + "/" + istr[6:8] 
                + ". The card is linked to a " + TypeList[int(istr[8])] 
                + " with the account number: " + istr[8:])
```

Now let me explain the actual error you are getting 'TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str' in string creation' is because it has finished parsing the seemingly complete first line or the part clipped out above and has now moved on to parse the second line. It sees the new line starts with the `+` so it must be the unary `+` since there is no operand on the left of the `+`. It is not applicable to the string operand that comes next, so it complains.

Answer (score 0):

Adding backslashes when creating string on multiple lines, should solve the problem:

```
ostr = istr + ": Was issued by " + IssuerList[int(istr[1])] + " in 20" \
+ istr[2:4] + ". The card expires on " + istr[4:6] + "/" + istr[6:8] \
+ ". The card is linked to a " + TypeList[int(istr[8])] \
+ " with the account number: " + istr[8:]
```