# How to fix certain 'Line too long' errors in a Python file?

Tags: python, flake8

I have the following line inside a for loop (i.e. it's indented by 4 spaces):

```
    abcdefgh_ijklm_nopqrstuvwxy = abcdefgh_ijklm_nopqrstuvwxy.append(abc_de)
```

The line is 80 characters long. How can I split it up so that it I do not get a 'Line too long' notification? Please note that I've changed the variable names for privacy reasons (not my code), but I can't modify the name of the variable, so naming it something shorter to fix the problem is not a viable option

As a secondary question, how would I split up a formatted string of the form:

```
data_header = f"FILE_{heading_angles}_{moment_of_inertia}_{mass_of_object}_{type_of_object}"
```

to span multiple lines?
I already tried

```
data_header = f"FILE_{heading_angles}_{moment_of_inertia}_"
              f"{mass_of_object}_{type_of_object}"
```

but that gives me an indentation error.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just a side note, but I recommend things like autopep8 for auto-formatting just so you don't have to worry about this much

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll check it out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope that these points answer your questions:

1. To simplify your expressions, try to replace the variables with simpler ones before the expressions. This may be inappropriate, if more serious operations are needed. For example:

```
a = abcdefgh_ijklm_nopqrstuvwxy
b = abcdefgh_ijklm_nopqrstuvwxy.append(abc_de)
a = b
```

2. In your case, try using a forward-leaning backlash (`\`) at the end of the line. For example:

```
if a == True and \
   b == False
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python) is a link from another discussion on a similar matter.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For you data_header example - you need brackets.

For example:

```
data_header = (
    f"FILE_{heading_angles}_{moment_of_inertia}_"
    f"{mass_of_object}_{type_of_object}"
)
```