# Is there a way to not put the { next to the declaration on a dict variable in python?

Tags: python

Is putting the { next to the variable declaration required by syntax (for a dict variable) or is there a way to put it on the next line because if I do it like this I have to go through each item and check them until I find the item I want to change:

```
var = {thingy1: 1, thingy2: 2, thingy3: 3, thingy4: 4, thingy5: 5}
```

I would like to do it like this:

```
var =
{
    thingy1: 1,
    thingy2: 2
}
```

I have seen some people doing it like this but I just want to know if putting the { next to the variable declaration is required by syntax or not:

```
var = {
    thingy1: 1,
    thingy2: 2
}
```

(sorry if its a stupid question im a bad programmer and ive just started learning python lol)

Comment: Why not [try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL2XH.png) it yourself to [find out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHlhG.png)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do a line break (line continuation) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python)

Comment: Please be aware that having many downvoted and deleted questions may result in a question ban. Consider to [edit] any [existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67092783/how-do-you-make-a-multi-line-dict-variable-without-making-it-look-ugly) into shape instead of re-asking them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always try it yourself first:

```
In [7]: var =                                                                   
  File "<ipython-input-7-3c8c4b28ffa8>", line 1
    var =
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


In [8]: var = \ 
   ...: { 
   ...:     "thing": "thing" 
   ...: }                                                                       

In [9]: var                                                                     
Out[9]: {'thing': 'thing'}
```

To answer your question, it's a SyntaxError to have nothing after the equal sign on a variable assignment. If you have some reason to continue the line you can use a `\` backslash as I've shown in the above example.

By convention you put them on the same line unless the line would be [too long](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) (line continuation techniques are also described in this link):

```
var = {"thing1": 1, "thing2": 2}
```

If the line would be very long (e.g. hard to read), you'd do it the vertical way:

```
var = {
    "thing1": 1,
    "thing2": 2,
    ...
    "thing50": 50,
}
```