# What does '\' means on Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df['Produit'].mean()\.reset_index()\.sort_values(by='Produit')
```

what does '\' means in this code ?

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Your question is unclear, where is the "\"?

Comment: It's [explicit line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation)

Comment: line continuation.  various different options on if you should use them.  code formatters (i.e. back) typically don't

Answer (score 0):

In this makes more sense like this:

```
df['Produit'].mean()\
             .reset_index()\
             .sort_values(by='Produit')
```

where the '', backslash is a [line continuation characters](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining).