# Line break issues in Spyder Python IDE

Tags: python, spyder, line-breaks

Consider the following list that breaks across lines:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 
     4, 5, 6]
```

When I run this directly from the editor in Spyder, I get: SyntaxError: unmatched ']'

If I move the whole expression to the same line, there is no error.

If I run the same code (with the line break) from a Jupyter notebook, there is no error.

If I develop this code directly from the IPython console, it leads me with '...:' and there is no error.

Are there any good practices or settings for implementing line breaks when writing scripts in Spyder?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do a line break (line continuation)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation)

Comment: @m13op22 be aware that many of the answers were written before the style guide change, and are now considered non-idiomatic.

Comment: That shouldn't be an error. Can you give more details? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks so much all. See my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a explicit line break: \

```
a = [1, 2, 3, \
     4, 5, 6]
```

Reference [Here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: But you shouldn't need it.

Comment: Hi all, thanks so much for the responses. @Peter Wood, you are right. This isn't actually an error. It had to do with the keyboard shortcut I was using to run the code directly from the script. Apologies. I am an R user and erroneously adapted a code execution approach. Just getting used to Python.