# What does '=\' operator mean in Python

Tags: python

so there is this piece of code I am trying to understand:

```py
rois, target_class_ids, target_bbox, target_mask =\
                DetectionTargetLayer(config, name="proposal_targets")([
                    target_rois, input_gt_class_ids, gt_boxes, input_gt_masks])
```

DetectionTargetLayer is a Keras subclass layer. So what does the operator =\ mean? Is it just the same as '='?

Comment: That's not an operator.  That's an equals sign with a line continuation.  The next line is appended to the end.

Comment: This code is a bit misleading because the slash in =\ is actually not related to equal sign at all (and could be any distance from it). It's the line continuation character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not an operator, the `\` is a line continuation chararacter.  It splits the line after the `=` and allows it continue on the next line.  PEP8 standards say to keep lines under 120 characters, and this line is pretty long, so the author broke it after the `=`.

Answer (score 0):

`\` is not used as an operator, instead, it is used as an equals sign with a line continuation.

I see where you are confused, the code isn't really clear.

`=\` is actually not related to equal sign at all.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```py
rois, target_class_ids, target_bbox, target_mask =\
                DetectionTargetLayer(config, name="proposal_targets")([
                    target_rois, input_gt_class_ids, gt_boxes, input_gt_masks])
```

is **IDENTICAL** to this code:

```py
rois, target_class_ids, target_bbox, target_mask = DetectionTargetLayer(config, name="proposal_targets")([target_rois, input_gt_class_ids, gt_boxes, input_gt_masks])
```

Because, as others have said, like in C, Bash, and many other languages, `\` at the end of a line tells the Python interpreter to treat the next line as the same line, and ignore the `\`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53162/17242583) talks in detail about the usage of the line-continuation token in Python.