# Fat`s formula on python

Tags: python, django

I have a formula:

```
%fat=495/(1.29579-0.35004(log(hips+waist-neck))+0.22100(log(growth)))-450
```

How did this fat formula on python? I make it:

```
from math import log


fat = 495 / (1.29579 - 0.35004 * log(self.hips + self.waist - self.neck) + 0.22100 * log(self.user.profile.growth)) - 450
```

But the meanings are far from the truth.
Link on calculator https://www.scientificpsychic.com/fitness/diet-calculator-ru.html

Comment: What is the expected value ("truth" in your question) and what results does your formula give?

Comment: I bet your original formula is using log base 10, while `math.log` defaults to log base e

Comment: Maybe in the original formular log is base 10. Python math.log is base e.

Comment: If you need log base 10, try (for example) `log(self.hips + self.waist - self.neck,10)`

Comment: or `math.log10`

Comment: @JakobLovern tnx, bro! It`s work!!!

Answer (score 0):

*(Note: This issue was solved in comments, I'm just adding an answer to mark the question as solved.)*

As I suggested in the comments, the issue comes in because [`math.log`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#power-and-logarithmic-functions) defaults to using base e, while most mathematicians<sup>1</sup> default to using base 10, and calling base e logarithms `ln`. There are two good solutions to work around this. First, if you need base 2 or 10, you should use `math.log2` or `math.log10`. The python 3 docs say:

> math.log2(x)
>
> Return the base-2 logarithm of x. This is usually more accurate than `log(x, 2)`

But if you're working in another base, use `log` and add the base as an arg, such as log<sub>3</sub>(x) =`log(x,3)`.

All that being said, this question should be solved as follows:

```py
import math

fat = 495 / (1.29579
           - 0.35004 * math.log10(self.hips + self.waist - self.neck)
           + 0.22100 * math.log10(self.user.profile.growth,10)) - 450
```

*Unrelated: Long lines of code can be fairly hard to read. [PEP8 recommends](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) keeping your code under 80 characters long. I've tried to format this code for legibility. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53162/8954291) explains how to break python code across lines*

---

1 | Sometimes you'll see mathematicians/programmers use `log` to refer to log base 2, usually in the context of programming or algorithms. Just something to be aware of!