# What does \ mean in kV file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am reading through some source code for KivyMD and I came across \ in a kV file. Can't find what this means. Probably a silly question but could anyone tell me... Thanks

```
<ButtonContentsText>
    lbl_txt: lbl_txt
    width:
        max( \
        root._min_width, \
        root.padding[0] + lbl_txt.texture_size[0] + root.padding[2] \
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python code is being embedded in Kivy language. You can see this by the use of `max` and operators. In Python, you can [continue a line with a backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53180/19846219). Thus

```py
<ButtonContentsText>
    lbl_txt: lbl_txt
    width:
        max( \
        root._min_width, \
        root.padding[0] + lbl_txt.texture_size[0] + root.padding[2] \
        )
```

is equivalent to

```py
<ButtonContentsText>
    lbl_txt: lbl_txt
    width:
        max(root._min_width, root.padding[0] + lbl_txt.texture_size[0] + root.padding[2])
```