# Is there a way to mimic the pipe operator from R in Python?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

See the example below. Is it possible to put each Python operation on a new line? If I have many operations, the code is not all visible. I need to scroll the VS Code window to the right. Thanks

```
# R code
data %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarise(avg_height=mean(height))

# Python code
data.groupby(['sex']).agg(avg_height=('height', 'mean')).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python, line breaks inside parentheses are ignored, so you could rewrite as:

```
(data
    .groupby(['sex'])
    .agg(avg_height=('height', 'mean'))
    .reset_index())
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python) post may be helpful.