# add count number of duplicate sub columns and keep other columns

Tags: pandas

Below example count duplicate numbers by column `x1` and `x2`. the output has `x1`,`x2` and `count`., I expect it keep `x3` (first row of duplicates) as well.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['A','B','C'],
    ['A','B','D'],
    ['A','D','C'],
    ['A','D','C']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['x1','x2','x3'])
print(df)

df1 = df.groupby(['x1','x2']).size().reset_index()
print(df1)
```

current output:

```
  x1 x2 x3
0  A  B  C
1  A  B  D
2  A  D  C
3  A  D  C

  x1 x2  0
0  A  B  2
1  A  D  2
```

expected output:

```
  x1 x2 x3 0
0  A  B C  2
1  A  D C  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby_agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) to keep `x3` in the output result:

```
>>> (df.groupby(['x1','x2'])
        .agg(x3=('x3', 'first'), cnt=('x1', 'size'))
        .reset_index())

  x1 x2 x3  cnt
0  A  B  C    2
1  A  D  C    2
```

Comment: great, what's the reason include everything into "()"?

Comment: This is a [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#groupby-aggregate-named). `agg` expects keyword arguments with the following format: `new_column=(column, function)` => the `function` is applied on `column` and the result is stored in `new_column`.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand. I enclosed the code in `( )` to have a single instruction on multiple lines. It avoid "\" at the end of each line. (This avoid the scrollbar). More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53162/15239951)